# J2ME, process a never-ending http connection line by line

Tags: java, http, java-me, connection

I have to write a simple http connection reader in J2ME who has to process a chunked connection line by line.

I tried this:

```
  connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open( url );
  inputStream = connection.openDataInputStream();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int c ;
    while (true) {
        c = inputStream.read();
        if (c == -1)
            break;
        if (c == 10) { // new line \n

            handler( baos.toString() );
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        }
        else
            baos.write(c);
    }
```

but it seems to start the entire process only when the server close the connection.

How do i have to manage new incoming lines without have to buffer everything ?

Thank you!

Comment: @org.life.java: Why did you change the indentation that way?

Comment: @thejh to make it more readable :)

Comment: @org.life.java: Why did you indent the second line more than the first one?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be impossible using HttpConnection, but it works with StreamConnection